# Using Three20 framework for make a Flickr Gallery on my iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, three20, flickr

Well,

I need to find a tutorial to learning how use Three20 framework with some tagged pictures on my flickr gallery.

I tried looking on the internet but many tutorial use the url carved and not the Reply from Flickr with the Flickr's API.

I've tried to see the flickr developer objective-c documentation but I can't understand what they mean.

Comment: The flickr api document can be found here:http://www.flickr.com/services/api/, basically, you need to implement a photo viewer in your three20 app, then implement a photoSource methods to send request to flickr api and then parser the returned XML or JSON. Then you need to show the photos in your photo viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20/) and open the TTCatalog target. that'll show you the implementation of three20 classes.